# Serialize Javaparser objects with Jackson Json

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, javaparser

I'm trying to serialize Javaparser objects with Jackson JSON, but it's pretty complicated as it is a third party library (I can't change/annotate the code) and there are circular dependencies within it.

My project is structured as such :

An object `Analysis` contains some lists of `WrappedNode` that may reference each other. Each `WrappedNode` contains a JavaParser [`CallableDeclaration`](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/blob/master/javaparser-core/src/main/java/com/github/javaparser/ast/body/CallableDeclaration.java).

When I try to map my `Analysis`, I've got an error :

```
JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.github.javaparser.metamodel.PropertyMetaModel["containingNodeMetaModel"]->com.github.javaparser.metamodel.SimpleNameMetaModel["declaredPropertyMetaModels"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.github.javaparser.metamodel.PropertyMetaModel["containingNodeMetaModel"]...
```

So, to get rid of the infinite recursion, I know I have to use `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")`, which I did on my `WrappedNode` class, but I think I should also annotate JavaParser classes using [Mix-in annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

The problem is that there is a lot of fields and a lot of classes, and I don't know which ones to annotate.

Thank's for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the [JsonPrinter](http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.2.8/com/github/javaparser/printer/JsonPrinter.html) class provided by JavaParser. It is a very recent addition (from version 3.2.8 I think) and it could not be perfect but you can use it super, super easily

Comment: This would be perfect, but as I am also using JavaSymbolSolver, I use the maven dependency 
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-symbol-solver-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.5</version>
</dependency> 
So I'm stuck with JP 3.2.4, am I not ?

Comment: Technically yes, but given I am the mantainer of the JavaSymbolSolver I can just do a release for you...

Comment: That would be very very nice :) Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem, we love to help our users! JavaSymbolSolver 0.5.6 has been released and it is based on JavaParser 3.2.10. It normally takes a few hours to propagate to Maven Central. If you are in an hurry you can just clone the repo from GitHub and run ./gradlew install to install a copy locally, otherwise in a few hours you will be able to get it from maven central